# How do I get the selected item to a value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add more items but whenever i do it gives me "out of Package" feedback when 300 and above is clicked. [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWy2X.png)

```
 $pledge = ($this->input->post('pledge') == 'a') ? 100 : 200;
            if($data['user']['accountType'] == 1){
                if($this->profile_model->savePledge($session['session_id'], $pledge)){
                    $note_message = 'Pledge successfully added';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('pledge', array('message' => $note_message,'class' => 'success'));
                    redirect(base_url('profile/give'));
                }else{
                    $err_message = 'Sorry an error occured try again';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('pledge', array('message' => $err_message,'class' => 'fail'));
                }
            }
```

I tried the methods below but 300 and above is still out of package

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $inputz = array (
    "valuez"  => array('a' => 100, 'b' => 200, 'c' => 300, 'd' => 400, 'e' => 500, 'f' => 600, 'g' => 700));
$pledge = $inputz["valuez"][$this->input->post('pledge')];
```

How do I get the selected item (i.e 300 and above)  to a value just like the 100 and 200?
 [The rest of the code on github](https://gist.github.com/valorm/ca7c83f88dd0e729624c1319b5f0d362)

Answer (score 0):

Add your options to the form validation method `in_list` (easy enough to find as its the only thing that gives that error):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pledge', 'Pledge Amount', 'required|in_list[a,b]', array('required'=>'You did not select any','in_list' => "Out of package"));
```

e.g. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

`in_list[a,b,c,d]`

In list isn't really anything special, it just checks to see if the value of the field is in the array `array(a,b,c,d)`. If you need to do anything beyond that it is suggested to make a custom callback or handle the logic in another way.